# need help getting reply from nodejs api

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to set up a nodejs server and cant get the responce from it via postman

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//configure app for body parser   
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);

//setup server port
var port = process.env.PORT || 2345;

//connect to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/helloapi', {
    useMongoClient: true
});

//API routes
var router = express.Router();

//test routes
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.json({message: "welcome to our api"});
});

//routs will all be with prefix /api
app.use('/api', router);

//fire up server
app.listen(port);

//print to console when server fireup
console.log("Server listening on port: " + port);
```

im starting mongod and its working fine, when i start the file i even see this:

`2017-12-12T13:34:21.828+0200 I NETWORK  [conn11] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53090 conn: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "2.2.33" }, os: { type: "Windows_NT", name: "win32", architecture: "x64", version: "10.0.16299" }, platform: "Node.js v9.2.1, LE, mongodb-core: 2.1.17" }`

but on postman when i send a get with http://localhost:2345/api/
i get could not get any responce

What am I doing wrong here?
thanks

Comment: Show the `/api` route

Comment: what is `router`? You haven't required it

Comment: you haven't called your router for /api give a path using ==>  const router= require('./file name');

Comment: i used this: var router = express.Router();
what sould i require?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error I used :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json);
```

And then I fixed it to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Now everything is working fine